# IE message Allow blocked content:- IE restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls? Why?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, activex

We have developed an ActiveX object that is called via JavaScript in browser..

We have implemented IObjectSafety and also we have registered this dll using regasm mydll.dll /tlb /codebase

When we open this page locally we get the message as:-

IE restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls? We then have to choose Allow blocked content for it to run..

However, there is no such msg when the page in run from the server...

Why is this message coming up locally? What is the solution to fix this from the code of the ActiveX object?

We have signed the ActiveX dll using VS2010 snk file...
We have implemented IObjectSafety for the activex dll...
We have registered this dll using regasm mydll.dll /tlb /codebase
If I had not implemented the above 2 steps then, would I also have had got the error when opening the page in IE locally as well as on server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to have signed your DLL with a self-generated .SNK file. You need buy a full-featured Authenticode signing certificate, issued by an accredited trusted authority. Do shop around, options ranges, e.g. from [this](http://www.thawte.com/code-signing/) to [this](https://www.thesslstore.com/promoads/cheap-code-signing.aspx).

Once you've obtained a certificate, here is [how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231196%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Supporting `IObjectSafety` is required, but it doesn't make your control automatically safe. You just declare that it is safe, it's a statement. If you get your control deployed on 1000 pcs, then someone creates a VBScript trojan abusing the API of your control, you might get sued for the false statement. To stay safe, you should use something like [`Sitelock` template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2007/09/18/developing-safer-activex-controls-using-the-sitelock-template.aspx).

However, if run your pages locally via `file://` protocol and **do the manual deployment** of your DLL, it's a different story. **You don't have to sign your control with Authenticode** in this case. However, all ActiveX controls (safe and unsafe) are disabled by default, for security reasons. More details: [Understanding Local Machine Zone Lockdown](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx). You can get around it using [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX).

Comment: There is no such msg when the page in run from the server... and we have used IobjectSafety to mark the object as safe.. do we still require to buy certificates?

Comment: @NachiketKamat, from what server, something like `localhost`? It might belong to a different IE security zone. Reset ALL IE settings to the defaults, unregister the control with `regsvr32 /u control.dll`, both on the client PC where you test it, then try again. Also note my update about `IObjectSafety`. Yes, I believe you still need the certificate if you're going to run your control off the web.

Comment: I have registered the control using regasm mydll.dll /tlb /codebase, and the admin is going to run this regasm command on all 1000 PCs.. So why are you asking me to unregister?

Comment: @NachiketKamat, if you do manual deployment and serve you pages from the local file system, that changes everything. See my update.

Comment: `localhost` belongs to "Internet" zone. `file://` belongs to "My Computer" zone. They have different default security settings. Right click your page in IE and check its zone in the Properties.